# window.innerHeight vs window.outerHeight to calculate density?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I had a problem when I started developing a simple app with PhoneGap, a Ruler. Most of my mobile background is with native Android, so I'm starting with that. I'm a begginer on javascript and html5, web development in general.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547716/how-to-draw-a-simple-ruler-with-javascript/12547974#12547974) you can see my first question related to the issue.

This was my first attempt to calculate how many pixels I had in one millimeter. This works fine in Android native code.

```
    public float getYdpi() {
        return displayMetrics.ydpi;
    }
function getPixelsPerMillimeter(){
    return YDpi/25.4f;        
}
```

But the millimeters markers were being drawn wrong. Finally after some trying I replaced the method as it follows

```
 function getPixelsPerMillimeter(){
    var pixelsPerMms = window.innerHeight/heightInMms;
    return pixelsPerMms;    
}
```

HeightInMms is calculated in native android code, simple math height in pixels divided by density pixels per inch, multiplied by 25.4, how many millimeters you have in one inch.

```
public float getPhoneHeightInMillimeters(){     
    metrics = gap.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();                   
    return (metrics.heightPixels     / metrics.ydpi)*25.4f;
```

Long story short, the dpi (or pixels per inch, which is my final goal) I get from native code, or using window.outerHeight is different than the one I get from window.innerHeight. Why?

Giving real values, I'm testing on a galaxy s2 device, with 800px height. window.outerHeight returns 800, as metrics.heightPixels, but window.innerHeight gives me 533. Why?

Comment: From MDN, window.outerHeight gets the height in pixels of the whole browser window. It represents the height of the whole browser window including sidebar (if expanded), window chrome and window resizing borders/handles.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a element with 1 inch width and then ask for clientWidth of the element (it is measured with pixels)

Example:

```
function getPixelsPerInch() {
  var d = document.createElement("div");
  var ret;
  d.style.opacity = 0;
  d.style.width = "1in";
  d.style.position = "fixed";
  d.style.padding = 0;
  document.body.appendChild(d);
  ret = d.clientWidth;
  document.body.removeChild(d);
  return ret; 
}
alert(getPixelsPerInch());
```

I suggest avoid doing unit calculations and relay on browser when/where possible, for example you can calculate **pixels per millimeter** this way:

```
function getPixelsPerMillimeter() {
  var d = document.createElement("div");
  var ret;
  d.style.opacity = 0;
  d.style.width = "1mm";
  d.style.position = "fixed";
  d.style.padding = 0;
  document.body.appendChild(d);
  ret = d.clientWidth;
  document.body.removeChild(d);
  return ret; 
}
alert(getPixelsPerMillimeter());
```

Or a more generic approach:

```
function getPixelsPer(unit) {
  var d = document.createElement("div");
  var ret;
  d.style.opacity = 0;
  d.style.width = unit;
  d.style.position = "fixed";
  d.style.padding = 0;
  document.body.appendChild(d);
  ret = d.clientWidth;
  document.body.removeChild(d);
  return ret; 
}
function getPixelsPerInch() {
  return getPixelsPer("1in");
}
function getPixelsPerMillimeter() {
  return getPixelsPer("1mm");
}
alert(getPixelsPerInch());
alert(getPixelsPerMillimeter());
alert(getPixelsPer("1cm")); // and so on...
```